# React native toggle component without state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just want to toggle SearchButton and SearchIcon , I use following code

```
  searchBarButton() {
    Actions.refresh();
    this.setState({ showSearchBar: !this.state.showSearchBar });
  }

 render() {
    if (this.state.showSearchBar) {
      return (
        <Header>
          <View style={styles.searchHolder}>
            <Item style={styles.searchBar}>
              <Icon name="ios-search" />
              <Input placeholder="Search" />
            </Item>
            <Button style={styles.searchButton} onPress={this.searchBarButton}>
              <Text>Search</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Header>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Header>
            <Button onPress={() => this.searchBarButton()} transparent>
              <Icon name="search" style={styles.bigblue} />
            </Button>
      </Header>
    );
  }
```

So basically It is very fast initially , But when my scene contains lots of items in flat List , There is like 1 to 2 seconds delay between toggle.I guess its due to re-rendering all items in page.

So How can I toggle this in more easier and efficient way without Re rendering whole page without using state

Comment: I think "transparent" on your Button component, does a lot of overdraw. If you are also using opacity changes on other components I'd first check on that. See this article to learn more about optimizing react-native and avoiding overdraw https://launchdrawer.com/i-made-react-native-fast-you-can-too-9e61c951ce0

Comment: Your initial approach to this problem is good. You didn't share your code for FlatList so I thought I'd chip in my 2 cents about it. If there is too much data for your FlatList then you should use `initialNumToRender` prop of FlatList. It specifies how many elements to render at any given time. This will reduce the overdraw possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to hide one of them by using `style` prop.

Just render both first, toggle one of them to be hidden(by using state),

> ```
> <Header>
>   <View style={[this.state.showSearchBar && styles.hidden]}>Button</View>
>   <View style=[{!this.state.showSearchBar && styles.hidden}]>Icon</View>
> </Header>
> ```

do not remove them from virtual dom(I don't know what to call it in mobile) completely

Comment: Ok how to change style in real time , sorry I am new to react

Comment: @Vishnu I updated answer. By using `this.state.showSearchBar`, if it is true, styles.hidden will be applied, otherwise, it will not be applied.

Comment: So I must have two header with one as display:hidden ?

Comment: @Vishnu If you want only one header, you can make Header common
`<Header><View style={styles.hidden}></View><View style={styles.show}></View></Header>`

Comment: Hi , I tried ur method , please see https://snack.expo.io/rkc3YH9Pb  , but its not working

Comment: @Vishnu Ah, there's no such thing like display: none in React-native. User opacity: 0 or height: 0 instead

Comment: If I give opacity 0 , two components position will be up and down,, I must give position absolute , which will affect my styles

Comment: Try to give both opacity: 0 and height: 0 @Vishnu

Comment: hi still same problem , When I change state , Whole screen re renders and there is 1 second flick

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to grab some UI library. Take a look at this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#utilities

You can just trow you your searchbar code in this

```
    <Collapse in={this.state.showSearchBar}>
      ...
    </Collapse>
```

And everything is taken care of very efficiently.

You just need to trow your button in an operator `{!showSearhBar && <Component/>}`

Also use [react dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) to check what re-renders